# Using heroku pg:backups:restore to Import to Heroku Postgres

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I am trying to copy a local PostgreSQL database to Heroku [per this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres).

Here is what I have done:

#### 1. Make a dump file

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres mydb > mydb.dump
```

#### 2.Upload dump file to aws my-bucket-name/db-backup folder.

```
aws s3 cp mydb.dump s3://my-bucket-name/db-backup/mydb.dump
```

#### 3. Generate a signed URL:

```
aws s3 presign s3://my-bucket-name/db-backup/mydb.dump --region us-east-2
```

#### 4. Verify that the signed URL is accessible.

Navigate to the presigned URL in an incognito tab of a browser. It works.

#### 5. Back up to Heroku using the generated signed URL

I am using double quotes around `GENERATED_URL` because I'm on Windows:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore --app my-app-name --confirm my-app-name "GENERATED_URL"
```

For example:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore --app my-app-name --confirm my-app-name "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-bucket-name/db-backup/mydb.dump?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIABCDVKE2GXCY3YXL7V%2F20200934%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200924T164718Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=fb2f51c0d7fbe1234e3740cf23c37f003575d968a1e4961684a47ac627fbae2e"
```

#### THE RESULT

I get the following errors:

```
Restoring... !
 !    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 !
 !    Could not initialize transfer
 !
 !    Run heroku pg:backups:info r021 for more details.
'X-Amz-Credential' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-Date' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-Expires' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-SignedHeaders' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'X-Amz-Signature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've found others with similar problems, but no solutions. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 5):

This is resolved. There were two issues.

1. PowerShell wasn't properly escaping characters. So, I switched to CMD.
2. The dump file was invalid.

This line of code produced an invalid dump file:

`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres mydb > mydb.dump`

Instead, I needed to use the following syntax:

`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d mydb -f mydb.dump`

After making that change, all worked smoothly.

Comment: I assume that `>` results in a non-compressed format?

Comment: does it work with Heroku dashboard-generated backups?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had the same issue and my solution was to copy the S3 URL which is formatted as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/<dump_file>.dump`. For some reason the pre-signed URL approach did not work but the public URL did.

Comment: Defeats the point of a pre-signed url...

Comment: I just used the S3 URL too (after making it Public) and it worked fine.  I couldn't get the pre-signed URL to work.